# Что значит ошибка "E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to"?

Tags: delphi

Проект находится по адресу: С:\Project\ , в нем же находятся файлы `file1.txt` и `file2.txt`.

При попытке сбилдить проект, всплывает 3 ошибки. Не пойму почему?

```
const
  ComFileHandle: array[3..4,1..2] of integer = ((-1,-1),(-1,-1));
```

...

```
function InitComFiles(NBlok: byte): byte;
var
  I : byte;
const
      CodeErr: array[3..4,1..2] of byte = ((13, 23),(14, 24));
      Res: array[1..2] of byte = (0,0);
begin
  Result:= $F;
  for I:= 1 to 2 do
   begin
     ComFileHandle[NBlok, I]:= FileOpen(Format('file%d.txt',[I]), $40); //Error
     if ComFileHandle[NBlok, I] < 0 then
       begin
         Res[I]:= CodeErr[NBlok,I];  //Error
         Result:= Res[I];
       end;
   end;
  if (Res[1]= CodeErr[NBlok,1]) and (Res[2]= CodeErr[NBlok,2]) then
    begin
      Result:=NBlok;
      Exit;
    end;
  if  MassivList[NBlok]= nil then   MassivList[NBlok]:= TList.Create //Error
     else  MassivList[NBlok].Clear;
  OpenBD(NBlok);
end;
```

Ошибка:

> [Pascal Error] E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to

Comment: А заодно проверьте возвращаемый тип `FileOpen`, он действительно имеет размерность Byte в вашей версии Delphi?

Comment: Вы же их константами объявили сами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка очевидна, вы пытаетесь присваивать новые значения константам. Сообщение вам об этом же и говорит: "Left side cannot be assigned to" - "нельзя присвоить значение левой стороне"

---

В Delphi также есть инструкция для компилятора, которая разрешит вам присваивать типизированным константам новые значения:

```
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
const
  AssignableConst: Integer = 0;
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
...
AssignableConst := 123;
```

Она также доступна в настройках проекта Project -> Options -> Compiler -> Assignable typed Constants.